# powershell - remote disk information unique description

Tags: powershell, diskspace

Need some assistance with the below script created, i can create a HTML report of the disk space for all remote machines i specified; however how do i add a meaningful description for each host i.e the pic below.

[image]

Script below

```
$Machine = @("Fakehost1", "Fakehost2", "fakehost3")

Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Machine -Filter "DriveType = '3'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Select-Object PsComputerName, DeviceID, 
    @{N="Disk Size (GB) "; e={[math]::Round($($_.Size) / 1073741824,0)}}, 
    @{N="Free Space (GB)"; e={[math]::Round($($_.FreeSpace) / 1073741824,0)}}, 
    @{N="Free Space (%)"; e={[math]::Round($($_.FreeSpace) / $_.Size * 100,1)}} | 
Sort-Object -Property 'Free Space (%)' | 
ConvertTo-Html -Head $Head -Title "$Title" -PreContent "<p><font size=`"6`">$Title</font><p>Generated on $date</font></p>" > $HTML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is to Sruce up the PSComputerName object in the same `Select-Object` command.  You're already doing a lot of calculated properties what's 1 more...

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Machine -Filter "DriveType = '3'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Select-Object @{N = 'PSComputerName'; E = { $_.PSComputerName + " : Description" }}, 
    DeviceID, 
    @{N="Disk Size (GB) ";e={[math]::Round($($_.Size) / 1073741824,0)}}, 
    @{N="Free Space (GB)";e={[math]::Round($($_.FreeSpace) / 1073741824,0)}}, 
    @{N="Free Space (%)";e={[math]::Round($($_.FreeSpace) / $_.Size * 100,1)}} | 
Sort-Object -Property 'Free Space (%)' | 
ConvertTo-Html -Head $Head -Title "$Title" -PreContent "<p><font size=`"6`">$Title</font><p>Generated on $date</font></p>" > $HTML
```

This tested good in my environment, but you will have to decide how to or what the actual description should be...  If you are in an AD environment maybe you can create a hash to hold the descriptions like:

```
$Descriptions = @{}
$Machine | 
Get-ADComputer -Properties Description |
ForEach-Object{ $Descriptions.Add( $_.Name, $_.Description ) }
```

Then change the PSComputerName expression like:

```
@{N = 'PSComputerName'; E = { $_.PSComputerName + $Descriptions[$_.PSComputerName] }}
```

This would reference the hash and return the value you got from the AD description attribute. Of course, that means the attribute has to be populated. But it's just 1 idea to demonstrate the point that the description must be mined from somewhere.

**Update:**

To answer your comment, You could manually specify the hash instead. use something like below, before the `Get-CimInstance` command.  Make sure to remove the previous AD stuff...

```
$Descriptions = 
@{
    Fakehost1 = "SQL Server for some bug app..."
    Fakehost2 = "File Server 1"
    Fakehost3 = "Another file server"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately i don't have access to the AD. How do i add the description into a list such that when the script pulls the space info it will check the list and pull in the specific description i wrote for that host i.e

ED001-SP01 = Web Server
ED001-SDB01 = SQL server for specific application

Comment: AD was an example the concept can be employed with a manually defined hash.  As a design preference I might change things up at that point by creating a collection of custom objects instead of using a simple string array, but above should work.

Comment: thanks, i did that but keeps on giving me error: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal and The hash literal was incomplete.



i have replaced the code with the below:

$Descriptions = @{Fakehost1 = "Web Server 01",Fakehost1 = "Web Server 02"}

Select-Object @{N = 'PSComputerName'; E = {$_.PSComputerName + ":" $Descriptions}},

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that I had posted a revised comment.  I modified the answer to include properly formatted code. It should work. Please comment back otherwise.

Comment: thank you, i added the updating comment but still recieve the error. I have placed the updated code im running on my original post and the error. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: You declared the `$Machine` array as if it is a has literal like `@{}`.  Therefore it's looking for you to assign values with the `=` operator.  You should have used an array sub-expression `@(...)` . For example `$Machine = @( "Fakehost1", "fakehost2" )`.  I corrected it in the question itself.  Please retry...